# MongoDB "Bad index key pattern"

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a collection called "Users" which contains several documents that represent individual users. Each user has an "email" field and a "password" field. I am attempting to specify a unique index on the "email" field but am getting some sort of error from the database.

My creation looks like the following:

```
db.users.createIndex( { "email": "hey@email.com" }, { unique: true } )
```

When I attempt to create this unique index, I am getting a response like the following:

```
{
"createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
"numIndexesBefore" : 1,
"errmsg" : "exception: bad index key pattern { email: \"hey@email.com\" }: Unknown index plugin 'hey@email.com'",
"code" : 67,
"ok" : 0
}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong? I was hoping I would be able to add users with the email/password combination and receive an error immediately if there is a user with this email in the database already.

If this is a conceptual issue, any advice or link to a helpful article would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's of course syntax error.
The correct way of creating unique index on email column is:

```
db.users.createIndex( { "email": 1 }, { unique: true } );
```

Hope that helps.